# Черный экран при установке amdgpu-pro на KDE Neon

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, kde

Установил KDE Neon, установил amdgpu-pro по [этой](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82_amd) инструкции (там для убунты, но по моему это все равно, ведь он ubuntu-based), после установки при перезагрузке у меня только черный экран и все. В tty еще могу зайти, а больше ничего не работает. Переустановка драйвера не помогла. Удалить тоже не выходит: uninstall скрипта в архиве почему-то не оказалось (хотя судя по инструкции должен быть), а на "apt autoremove amdgpu-pro*" мне пишет кучу ошибок вида "Не удалось найти пакет...". Подскажите как быть дальше? Могу в принципе систему полностью переустановить пока не успел еще "обжиться", но мне все равно нужен способ нормально установить драйвер.

P.S. У меня ноут Sony Vaio с процессором amd и его же графикой.

Comment: Вы сумели установить? Сейчас пробую по-всякому и пока не вижу дороги к светлому будущему :(

Answer (score 1):

Удаление amdgpu-pro:

1. Заходим в режим восстановления
2. Заходим в консоль от root
3. Получаем доступ на запись `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`
4. Переходим в папку, откуда устанавливали amdgpu-pro
5. Выполняем `amdgpu-pro-uninstall`
6. Выполняем `reboot`